# Bootstrap: Prevent 'wells' from wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my current website using bootstrap, I have a set of '[wells](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells)' within a [container-fluid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container). The effect I am trying to achieve is to have each well is side by side in one row. This was fine for a few wells. However, now I have added more wells and I have begun testing on smaller resolutions.

Now, when the wells reach the edge of the browser window, they wrap around. This is **not** the behavior I'd like. Instead, I would like a horizontal bar to appear and allow users to scroll sideways to view the rest of the wells. All the wells should be in the same row, irrespective of screen resolution, the number of wells, and the width of the well's contents.

Here is a brief section of code to give you an idea of my structure:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span">
      <div id="pipelinesPackagesViewPane" class="well well-sm">
        <h2> Well 1 </h2>
        <p> Long line of texxxtttttttttttttt </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span">
      <div id="pipelinesPackagesViewPane" class="well well-sm">
        <h2> Well 2 </h2>
        <p> Long line of texxxtttttttttttttt </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span">
      <div id="pipelinesPackagesViewPane" class="well well-sm">
        <h2> Well 3 </h2>
        <p> Long line of texxxtttttttttttttt </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MORE WELLS HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I using the correct Container? How can I achieve this 'no wrap' row result?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want the wells to stretch or will they have a set (max) width? meaning, will the scrolling need to be applied to the entire line or to the individual wells...?

Comment: ...because if the first one, then @Danko's answer is the correct one, otherwise apply the overflow to the wells individually and set their (max) width...

Comment: Yes the wells do, and should, stretch. Thanks for helping me clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need some custome CSS to get that result use this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row wells"> // ADD Class "wells"
    <div class="span">
```

Then on **CSS**

```
.row.wells {
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:auto;
    }
.span {
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

Check this [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/7fx1fwCnEn)

Comment: Thanks Danko, this was exactly what I want. I had to disable some of my other css to get it to work though(.span had float=left;)
However, now I'm getting the effect of 'steps' for each well. See here: http://www.bootply.com/Vum85EvjL6

Ideas on how to make all the wells align on the top, not the bottom?

Comment: @pcb glad to help u .. vertical-align chekc this http://www.bootply.com/x2slSkLKx2